# How do I pass the event and variable in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

This works in IE, but not Firefox.  I understand that window.event does not exist in Firefox, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to make it work.

HTML: `<tr onclick="getDETAILS('getTASKS');"`

Javascript:

```
  function getDETAILS(action) {
     if (window.event.ctrlKey) { 
        //doing something with action
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-browser solution:

```
<tr onclick="getDETAILS('getTASKS', event);">
```

**JS:**

```
function getDETAILS(action, e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('do stuff');
    }
}​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/McpKf/)

The `event` object will be passed to the function's formal parameter `e` in all modern browsers.

If the passed `event` object is `undefined` (older versions of IE), `e` is set to `window.event`.

Answer (score 1):

**The following works with IE, Firefox and Chrome.** (latest versions)

HTML:

```
<tr onclick="getDETAILS(event, 'getTASKS');">
```

JavaScript:

```
function getDETAILS(evt, action) {
  if(evt.ctrlKey) {
    //doing something with action
  }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vYUS8/2/